# I get An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'

Tags: vb.net

I keep getting a InvalidCastException each time I use this code. Can someone help? I am working on a program called Crystal. Crystal is a library for all of your games.

```
 Label1.Text = "Please wait..."
    'This will get the game's info so it can use it for REASONS.
    Label1.Text = "Getting game info..."
    Dim fileReader As String
    fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(gamepath \ "crystal\gamename.txt")    '<-------- Error Here

    'This will check the contents, just to make sure that it is correct.
    Label1.Text = "Now checking contents..."
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(gamepath \ "crystal") Then
        Label1.Text = "Yup. This is a Crystal game."
    Else
        MsgBox("This is NOT a crystal game. Make sure the crystal folder is in the package. ")
        Me.Close()
    End If
    'Crystal Folder Files

    'This will check for the gamename.txt
    Label1.Text = "Checking crystal folder data..."
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(gamepath \ "crystal\gamename.txt") Then
        Label1.Text = "Found gamename.txt"
    End If
    'This will check for the image.png
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(gamepath \ "crystal\image.png") Then
        Label1.Text = "Found image.png"
    End If

    'This will check for start.bat
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(gamepath \ "crystal\start.bat") Then
        Label1.Text = "Found start.bat"
    End If
    ' This will create the folder the game is going to be in.

    ' This will extract the game to C:\Crystal\library
    Label1.Text = "Extracting Game files..."
    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(gamepath, "C:\Crystal\library")
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate where the exception is thrown. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: `gamepath \ "crystal\gamename.txt"` The backslash \ operator is for integer division. You're probably trying to concatenate `gamepath` with your string, so you want the string concatenation & operator or the + operator. (Or to use `System.IO.Path.Combine()`)

Comment: Please add `Option Strict On` to the top of your code file or set it in your projects properties.